# Ubuntu 14.04: A "click" after system halt

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, acer

As I'm new to this, I don't know of this should be like that or not.

Back story:
I managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 (Elementary OS Freya, but this counts as Ubuntu :P) on my UEFI machine (Acer aspire E5-511), after the installation and a restart, I got a Grub Minimal Bash instead of the traditional Grub, so I couldn't boot to Ubuntu, then I managed to repair it.
I was so happy to see my new system boot up, it was running well, with 0 driver issues. But the problem appeared after I shut down the notebook: The notebook won't shut down, the system hangs at "System will halt now" with the fan running at full speed. After 3 hours of searching I managed to solve it (blacklisting 2 modules, I don't remember the names cause I just copy-paste the command) and HURRAY!! system shuts down and reboots normally!!
Another BUT! When the notebook turns off, I hear a "click" like if I pressed the power button for a few seconds to force shutdown, this doesn't happen with Windows (pre-installed) the notebook turns off without any noise, only happens with Linux.

The question is: Why this "click" happens? Is it harmful to my computer? How can I fix it?

PS: sorry for the bad English :P

Additional information:
All packages are updated, no additional drivers found.

Comment: Could you record the sound and share with us?

Comment: @mertyildiran hold the power button of your PC to force shutdown, it makes a "click" and shuts down at the same time, that's the sound it makes

Comment: Elementary OS Freya does not count as Ubuntu, and is off topic here! Check out http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Sounds like mechanical arm of the HDD.

Comment: @mikewhatever sorry!! I didn't know there was an eOS stackexchange! I'm new here :P

Comment: Great, now you do. Here is a [help section](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound is probably coming from your **BIOS speaker** and there is nothing to worry about. Not every laptop motherboard has a BIOS speaker.

BIOS speaker is an optional gadget for a motherboard.

It is probably a driver problem so it is software related. But this sound is not a harmful sound and you don't have to reinstall your driver.

**BIOS speaker:**

[image]

Comment: @Trillian You're welcome friend.